# What's wrong with this tcpdump syntax or will it produce different result?

Tags: tcpdump

tcpdump -nnvi any port 514 -l | grep -i 'urls,events,flows,ids-alerts'

Will it match ulrs events flows ids-alerts or will consider everything as one word ?

Answer (score 0):

It will consider everything as one word.

Read the [Grep manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) to figure out how `grep` works, there's plenty of resources online.

Answer (score 0):

So that's *not tcpdump syntax,* first of all. The tcpdump command ends at the `|`, and the 'grep' command starts instead.

The search filter in grep is *not* a comma-separated list; if you use commas they will just be taken literally, and the whole thing will be considered one word.

grep uses regular expressions, with the POSIX BRE syntax, and supports alternative branches using the `\|` separator (or just `|` if you use egrep, which uses the POSIX ERE syntax instead). However, commas will just be taken literally.